# Как проверить есть ли в txt файле определенный текст?

Tags: java, url

Мне надо сделать так чтобы программа проверяла правильно сгенерирован этот текст.

Там написано  к примеру `c4ca4238a0b923820dcc509a6f75849b`, как мне это сделать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Загрузить файла можно с помощью Java NIO:

```
URL website = new URL("http://www.url.com/имя_файла.txt");
ReadableByteChannel rbc = Channels.newChannel(website.openStream());
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("FILE_NAME.txt");
fos.getChannel().transferFrom(rbc, 0, Long.MAX_VALUE);
```

В Java 8 узнать содержится ли строка в файле можно так(используя Stream API):

```
boolean check = Files.lines(Paths.get(FILE_NAME.txt), StandardCharsets.UTF_8).anyMatch("c4ca4238a0b923820dcc509a6f75849b"::equals);
```

`Files.lines()` - создает стрим из файла
`Paths.get(FILE_NAME)` - имя файла
`anyMatch()` - возвращает `true`, если хотя бы один из элементов стрима соответствует условию

Comment: Там вопрос был не совсем про файл прямо на Windows там было написано JAVA URL это значит проверка по URI ссылке текст который записан на сайте в файле если он совпадает тогда продолжаем работу я писал это ночью поэтому такой глупый вопрос задал если вы еще здесь можете изменить пример и написать по URL ссылке (Но все равно спасибо за код достаточно полезно будет для двухэтапной аунтификации в программе)

Comment: @kasai т.е. по ссылке доступен файл, нужно проверить текст в этом файле?

Comment: Да можете скинуть другой пример кода?

Comment: @kasai можно сначала загрузить файл а потом сравнить. Добавил код

Comment: Спасибо чуть позже проверю если что еще раз напишу

Comment: Блин по сути это вообще не удобно выходит загружает файл по URL и еще потом проверять на компьютере пользователя так очень легко взломать программу я думаю по URL с зашифрованным соединением было бы труднее у меня в программе для каждого пользователя будет свой ключ аунтификации можете еще раз изменить код только уже на чтение файла по ссылке и еще я так и не понял как сделать обратное с вашим кодом если файл не соответствует тексту который на сайте в файле тогда `System.exit 0 server.disconnect(close)` они просто не входят в этот код я даже не понял почему